# Set the background image on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I want to set the background image of a button dynamically. (not using CSS classes).

I tried to achieve this by setting the `style.backgroundImage` property of the button as shown below. `getOnMouseOverImage` is bound to the `onmouseover` event and the button is passed as `this`.

```
myapp.ui.Button.prototype.getOnMouseOverImage = function(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url( \'" + myapp.core.ImageStore.getInstance().getImageURL(this.buttonId) + "\')'"
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

The above code doesn't seem to change the `backgroundImage` property of the button. How do I achieve this?

Comment: if you are correctly passing in the element you want to effect this should work.  There really isn't much need for event.preventDefault() or .stopPropagation() in this instance but they shouldn't really have an effect one way or the other.  Using the :hover in css is a much better way to handle this type of task.  CSS takes much less horsepower than javascript, and this is a one way function.  So you will have to have a "OnMouseOut" or similar function to revert the background.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have a simmer method to handle mouse out as well. I cannot have CSS because image is dynamic and cannot predict which is the image is going to be.

Comment: gottcha.  Make sure that your element is coming through correctly. your syntax looks correct.  I would just slap a `debugger;` in the function and check it out in chrome's dev tools.  Generally when its something simple like this that give you fits, its because of some minor issues that you would never think of until you start to dig.  Sorry I'm not more help, what you have looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an extra '

```
event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url( \'" + myapp.core.ImageStore.getInstance().getImageURL(this.buttonId) + "\')**'**"
```

I believe it should look like this

```
 event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url( \'" + myapp.core.ImageStore.getInstance().getImageURL(this.buttonId) + "\')"
```

No sure if that's the problem, however since I can't comment I'm going to post this as an answer.

EDIT: in fact, I'm not even sure you need the apostrophe's

```
 event.target.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + myapp.core.ImageStore.getInstance().getImageURL(this.buttonId) + ")"
```

Comment: Spot on. Yes extar '  was the issue.Thanks